# Evo PDF page index in table

Tags: c#, evo

I am using EVO Pdf to generate PDF,ie URL to PDF conversion is used.I have many dynamic sections in HTML to show student details .I have a table which contains entry for each student.I need to add page number in this table to identify student.ie in which page of PDF Student details will come?